# Creating Dynamic functions in ejs for each post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

i have a feed in my blog where every users post are shown, this is rendered dynamically using ejs. and there is a comment div tag which isn't displayed until the user clicks the comments button ..

**this is my ejs file**

```
<% posts.forEach(post => { %>
            <div class="h-1">
               <%= post.createdBy.name %> <span >  <%= post.createdAt.toDateString() %></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="title" >
            <a href="/post/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.title %> </a>
          </div>
          <div class="b-post">
            <%= post.body %>
          </div>
          <div class="options">
              <img src="/img/icons/comment-L.svg" alt="" onclick="commentDrop()" > Comments       
      
          </div>
          <div class="c-section" id="comments" style="display: none;">
            <div class="ad-com">
              <form method="POST"  id="commer" action="/post/addcomment">
                <input type="hidden" id="postId"  name="postId" value="<%= post.id %>">
              <div class="img">
                <i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="texter" id="texter" class="form-control" placeholder="add a comment">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="send" type="submit">comment</button>
          </form>
            </div>
  <% }) %>
```

and the function commentDrop() is called onclick.

**this is my javascript file**

```
<script>
    function commentDrop(){
      var x = document.getElementById("comments");
      if (x.style.display === "none"){
        x.style.display = "block"
      }
      else{
        x.style.display = "none"
      }
    }
  </script>
```

for some reason it is only the first post commentdrop function that is working ..if i click another post comment it works only for the first one.. please help thank you

Comment: "still works for only the first one"? What do you mean by works? All `commentDrop` does is change the Element with a `'comments'` id to `display:block;` or `display:none;`.

Comment: the display works only for the first post, but doesn't work for the rest of the posts on the feed

Comment: That loop creates invalid HTML on multiple levels. To start, you can have only one HTML `id` attribute value per page. I personally recommend creating your Elements like `const example = document.createElement(tagName);` then you can just do like `example.onclick = someFunc`. When creating elements like that you don't need to get them, just use dot access.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're having that specific problem because the **getElementById** function, only returns the first element that matches that id and in this case, it will only return the first rendered because they all share the same id, you have an id property on your post object, so you could set an attribute with that ID on the comments element, and finally pass that id to the function so it can get the specific element.

Sadly i cannot replicate this exactly to help you but the following code might give you an idea of what i mean.

```js
    <script> 
    function commentDrop(id) {
        var x = document.querySelector(`div[data-postId = ${id}]`);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block"
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none"
        }
    } 
    </script>
```

```html
<% posts.forEach(post => { %>
    <div class="h-1">
        <%= post.createdBy.name %> <span >  <%= post.createdAt.toDateString() %></span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title" >
        <a href="/post/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.title %> </a>
    </div>
    <div class="b-post">
        <%= post.body %>
    </div>
    <div class="options">
        <img src="/img/icons/comment-L.svg" alt="" onclick="commentDrop(<%= post.id %>)" > Comments       
    </div>
    <div class="c-section" id="comments" data-postId="<%= post.id %>" style="display: none;">
        <div class="ad-com">
            <form method="POST"  id="commer" action="/post/addcomment">
                <input type="hidden" id="postId"  name="postId" value="<%= post.id %>">
                <div class="img">
                    <i class="far fa-user-circle"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="texter" id="texter" class="form-control" placeholder="add a comment">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="send" type="submit">comment</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }) %>
```